# Multiple Zuul routes to one service

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Most of the examples that I see are one route definition to one service.

so this sort of thing:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    myserver:
      path: /mypath/**
```

Lets say that I want to route several routes to one service so in effect it would be like this:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    myserver:
      path: /mypath/**, /anotherpath/**
```

This isn't allowed in the configuration file and neither are you allowed to have the same route name twice.  Is there any real way to do this?

Comment: this question+answer just solved another issues for me: what if you want a unified API routing to many services? e.g. i have 3 services and want them to be all reachable via /services/**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It may be possible with something like this, but I've not tried it

```
zuul:
  routes:
    myserver_mypath:
      path: /mypath/**
      serviceId: myserver
    myserver_another_path:
      path: /anotherpath/**
      serviceId: myserver
```

Comment: Can confirm, works fine. Using it to selectively expose parts of an API.

Comment: @spencergibb Can't we use array for value of `path` attribute ?

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: @spencergibb, what's the difference between /mypath/** and /mypath/*... or the one with single '*' and the one with double '*' ?

Comment: double ** mean any depth on slashes, read here [link](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

Comment: can you share with us the source of your answer ? i couldn't find anything about this in the docs ? Thank you